# D3 Force layout - update nodes and maintain force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

How can I update a D3.js force layout with new nodes as the underlying data changes. At the moment I am able to generate the force layout and all nodes settle nicely on the chart. If I change the underlying data by removing, adding or editing nodes how can I do this and maintain the force layout, i.e. nodes settling on their own in the allocated chart space.

Here is part of my code which draws the nodes (circles) onto the chart:

```
var nodeCirclesInner = svg.selectAll("#innerCircle")
    .data(nodes, getPositionKey);

nodeCirclesInner
    .exit()
    .remove()

nodeCirclesInner
    .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.cx; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.cy; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; }) 
        .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2); })

inner = nodeCirclesInner
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("id", "innerCircle")
    .attr("class", "node_circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.cx; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.cy; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2); })
    .on("mouseover", mouseOver)
    .on("mouseout", mouseOut)       
    .call(force.drag);
```

The issue is the transition. I am setting the X and Y co-ordinates which is fine but results in many of the nodes overlapping. I would like the nodes to 'settle' on the chart without any overlapping as they do when the chart is originally generated.

Nodes which are removed from the underlying data are correctly removed from the layout.

Comment: Why are you using a transition here? Would you not just restart the force layout?

Comment: I'd like existing points to stay (transition) to a new position or remain still. New points should enter the visualisation from beyond the border as when originally initiated. Keeping existing points from moving excessively will help a user understand the transition as the underlying data changes.

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused. What would you like to happen exactly? In particular, how are the positions of the new nodes determined if you don't run the force layout?

Comment: I have a slider which filters data for the visualisation. I'd like existing nodes to shift to their new positions and still remain in the force layout, i.e retain drag capability. At the moment existing nodes move to a their new location but overlap, i.e. they do not remain in the force layout.

Comment: They overlap with what? How are the new positions determined?

Comment: Thanks for replying Lars. Here's the situation. New data is added to the chart as a force layout, each circle ultimately settles into a position on the chart so as none of the circles overlap. What I'd like to accomplish when the underlying data changes is to have a) circles removed due to data not existing anymore b) new nodes added to the force layout, i.e. they 'join' the existing circles on the chart and finally c) circles still existing in the data to be re-positioned (scale will have changed) but still remain in the original force layout. Items (a) and (b) are working fine.

Comment: You're not using a scale in the code you've posted -- where does that come in?